# Why does a value assignment nested loop, assign more than expected times?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I have a nested dictionary. The original dictionary has i keys, and each of these i keys, map j other keys to a list. 
I want to append each list a value . Since I know the keys of the dictionaries, I iterate over keys in a  `for(i) x for(j)`  loop, and expect `i*j` assignment. but I get `i*i*j` assignment. Where is my mistake?

I tried also to iterate through dictionary using standard `for i,j in dic.items()`, but I got more assignments than expected again.

```
# creating empty dictionary
dic_2 = {}
for i in range (10):
    dic_2[i] = []

dic = {}
for i in range (10):
    dic[i] = dic_2

# =========================================
# appending values
counter = 0
for i in range (10):
#     print("counter = ", counter,'_________', "i = ", i)
    for j in range (10):
#         print("__", "counter = ", counter,"j = ", j)
        counter += 1
        dic[i][j].append(counter)
dic
```

I expect

```
dic[0][0] = [0]
```

but I get

```
dic[0][0] = [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
```

Comment: You're assigning the same inner dictionary to every entry of the outer dictionary, so you're looping over the same 10 lists and coming back to the same one every 10 iterations.  It starts at 1 because you increment the counter before assigning the first entry.

Comment: Can you share your full expected output!

Comment: Thank you @lehiester,  however the main question for me is that, if the incrementation of variable counter (line17: `counter += 1`) occurs 100 times totally, why does the appending process (line18: `dic[i][j].append(counter)`) occurs 1000 times.

Comment: @Davesh, that would be the day :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every entry of `dic` is a reference to the same dictionary, `dic_2`.  To get a separate list for every `i,j`, you need to create lists in a nested loop, because the current code uses the same 10 lists for every `i`.

```
for i in range(10):
    dic[i] = dict()
    for j in range(10):
        dic[i][j] = list()
```

Comment: I still don't know how and why, but this way it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this code suitable for your requirement.

```
K = 10  # your range 
dic = {j:{i:[(K*j)+i] for i in range(K)} for j in {i:[i] for i in range(K)}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question for me is that, if the incrementation of variable counter (line17: counter += 1) occurs 100 times totally, why does the appending process (line18: dic[i][j].append(counter)) occurs 1000 times.